# Clearcase Albd service not available

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

After Windows 10 update , Clearcase ALBD service is not available anymore and i can't seem to find it either, is there a way get back albd service to work instead of uninstall and install Clearcase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the albd service essentially uses the wrong slash in the executable path. You can manually readd the albd service using this command line:

```
SC create albd type= own start= auto binpath= "C:\Program Files (x86)\RationalSDLC\clearcase\bin\albd_server.exe" displayname= "Atria Location Broker" depend= RpcSs/TcpIp/PolicyAgent/seclogon obj= (albd account name) password= (albd password)
```

Yes it's long, but I just did this this past week when the 1709 update rolled in and erased my albd service.

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: It works, but i can't understand how abld service uses the wrong slash ? can you please elaborate on that point , i had the same issue with the update 1709

Comment: If you run "SC qc albd" on a fresh standard install, you'll notice that the path uses the / and not the \ character. Longstanding legacy issue (the older installer did this too, and it didn't really start causing issues until the Windows 10 updaters, though some security updates also killed the albd service before...)

Answer (score 0):

First, this depends on the exact version of ClearCase you are installing in your Windows 10.

For instance, see "[ALBD missing after server installation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21259168)", because the `sitedefs.dat` file does not have the current ALBD username and password.
But that is for old versions of ClearCase.

Also, make sure you don't see that albd service in your Windows services, by typing `services.msc` ([as seen here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177467)).

The safest solution remains a clean un-install, reboot, full re-install, reboot.

Comment: ClearCase left the "sitedefs.dat" file behind in 7.0 or 7.1. It currently uses IBM Installation Manager.